# ystockquote.get_historical_prices cannot handle dynamic dates

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, yahoo-finance

I'm trying to build a portfolio management program, using ystockquote.

I can scrape prices using

```
ystockquote.get_historical_prices(y, '2013-11-01', '2013-11-11')
```

where y loops through a list of symbols ie. ('MSFT', 'F', 'MMM')
I want the dates to be dynamic, but the following code

```
print sDate
print eDate

for y in depot_sym:
print ystockquote.get_historical_prices(y, sDate, eDate)
```

produces the following

```
2013-09-30
2013-11-19                                                                      
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                
File "C:\***\deriv4\test.py", line 26, in <module>       
print ystockquote.get_historical_prices(y, sDate, eDate)                      
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\ystockquote.py", line 156, in get_historical_prices                                                                           
'a': int(start_date[5:7]) - 1,                                              
TypeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ystockquote.get_historical_prices()` expects strings in the format "YYYY-MM-DD", rather than `date` objects, as the second and third arguments. Try casting your dates using

```
sDate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: wonderful, thank you - this part seems to be the most opaque part of learning python, i think.